# Pull from each array if true in JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, if-statement

I'm creating a random password generator, and it's working well.  However, I've noticed that my `generatePassword()` function doesn't always pull from each array when the condition for each `if` statement is true.  For example:

```
function generatePassword() {
  // The arrays below are the arrays from which my generatePassword function can pull characters.
  const lowercase = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
  const uppercase = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "X"];

let charSet = [];

const passLength = prompt("Choose a length for your password. (This should be any amount between 8 and 128 characters.)");
  if (!isNaN(passLength) && passLength >= 8 && passLength <= 128) {
    const passLc = confirm("Should the password contain lowercase letters?");
    if (passLc) {
      for(let i = 0; i < lowercase.length; i++) {
        charSet.push(lowercase[i]);
      }
    }

    const passUc = confirm("Should the password contain uppercase letters?");
    if (passUc) {
      for(let i = 0; i < uppercase.length; i++) {
        charSet.push(uppercase[i]);
      }
    }

} else {
    prompt("Sorry, that entry is invalid. Please enter a value between 8 and 128.");
  }
  console.log(charSet);
  return password;
}

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
```

Is there a way to ensure that my function pulls from each array when the user's answer is true for each condition?  Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
Apologies for the confusion!

- The `charSet` array is a blank array that I'm using to compile an array of all of my smaller array indexes, and then using that to pull random characters.
- As far as I understand it, the purpose of getRandomInt is to pull random index items for the `randomIndex` constant from the `charSet` array.

Comment: Looks like you haven't shared all the relevant code, what is the purpose of `getRandomInt()` and `charSet`? How are you creating the contents of `password`?

Comment: At first glance, it seems that there is no problem in the code example you provided. Please provide more information to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Maharramoff, thanks!  Since I'm super new at JS, it could be that maybe there isn't a problem.  I just want to make sure that all array elements for which conditions are true are pulled from and included randomly. :) For instance, if I were to add special characters here, I want to make sure that those aren't randomly excluded if the user chooses to include them.

Answer (score -1):

I think I have come across a cleaner code to generate password:

```
Math.random().toString(36).slice(2, 10)
```